# dashDB service plan was not able to recognise with configuration files provided by IBM MobileFirst 8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, dashdb, mobilefirst-bluemix

We are trying to create IBM MobileFirst 8.0 Container for bluemix by following the MobileFirst containers tutorial in : https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/bluemix/mobilefirst-server-using-scripts/#setting-up-the-mobilefirst-and-analytics-servers-on-ibm-containers

As per the tutorial, we have created the MobileFirst 8.0 Analytics container and created dashDB transactional service in Bluemix. Before creating MobileFirst server image we have set up the dashDb service using **prepareserverdb.sh** script to set the database values in **server.env** file, but here we are getting an error saying that the serevice dashDB does not exist in the current users origanisation/spaces.

Any suggestions or solutions on how to connect are appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you check to make sure that you are logged in to the correct CF org/space? You can check this by `cf target` from the command-line. Make sure that matches where your service exists in Bluemix.

Comment: Can you add the exact error message you are seeing when running the script?

Comment: There are two transactional plans in the Bluemix dashDB service : `Enterprise for Transactions 2.8.500` and  
`Enterprise for Transactions 12.128.1400` 
Does the service you created belong to one of these two?
To find the exact plan name, login to the org/space where the service was created and run `cf service <your-service-name>`

Comment: In prepareserverdb.properties, what I can see is the value u have for DB_TYPE=dashDB.

Since you are directly passing all the DB_HOST, PORT Details, please use 
DB_TYPE=DB2.

If you have the dashDB service exists on the same space where you are trying to deploy MFP server, you can set DB_TYPE=dashDB and set ADMIN_DB_SRV_NAME=<your_dashDB_service_name>

other DB properties as empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use DB_TYPE in your prepareserverdb.properties as

```
DB_TYPE=DB2
```

instead of `DB_TYPE=dashDB`